# Energy-momentum relation for Dirac spinor in curved spacetime

Tags: gravity, dirac-equation, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Consider the Dirac equation in curved spacetime

\begin{equation}
(i\gamma^\mu\nabla_\mu+m)\psi=0
\end{equation}

where $\gamma^\mu=e^\mu_a\gamma^a$ is the curved spacetime Gamma matrices, and the covariant derivative $\nabla_\mu=\partial_\mu+\omega^{ab}_\mu\Gamma_{ab}$ is given by the spin connection $\omega^{ab}_\mu$.

Now how may I derive the energy-momentum relation \begin{equation}
g^{\mu\nu}p_\mu p_\nu=m^2
\end{equation}
assuming the spinor function $\psi$ can be taken, in approaximation, as the wave function of a Dirac fermion?